# In Elasticsearch, how can I aggregate data from nested fields and their parent document?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-opensearch

Give a `sales` index with this mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "amount": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date_time||epoch_millis"
      },
      "events": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "created_at": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "date_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "fees": {
            "properties": {
              "amount": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "credit_debit": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I query for the following?

- for each `sales.id`
- …that were `created_at` in a specific range
- show:

  - the `sales.id`
  - the `sales.amount`
  - max (i.e. latest) `sales.events.created_at`
  - total `sales.events.fees.amount`

My end goal is to have a CSV file with the results. Any solution would work, including:

- create a new index and reindex with some calculations
- an advanced aggregation query
- a Kibana SQL query
- a Kibana visualisation
- something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query in order to extract the information you need:

```
GET /sales/_search?filter_path=**.key,**.amount,**.created_at,**.total_fees.value,**.latest.value
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "2023-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00",
              "lte": "2023-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "pages": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 1000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "id"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "fields": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": [
              "amount",
              "created_at"
            ]
          }
        },
        "events": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest": {
              "max": {
                "field": "events.created_at"
              }
            },
            "total_fees": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "events.fees.amount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to paginate to the next page because there are more than 1000 buckets, you can do so by using the same query and adding the `after` parameter and specifying the `id` of the very last bucket of the preceding page:

```
GET /sales/_search?filter_path=**.key,**.amount,**.created_at,**.total_fees.value,**.latest.value
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "2023-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00",
              "lte": "2023-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "pages": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 1000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "id"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "after": {"id": "xyz"}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "fields": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": [
              "amount",
              "created_at"
            ]
          }
        },
        "events": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest": {
              "max": {
                "field": "events.created_at"
              }
            },
            "total_fees": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "events.fees.amount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can export the results to CSV using the following `jq` command:

```
jq -r '.aggregations.pages.buckets[] | [.key.id, .fields.hits.hits[]."_source".amount, .fields.hits.hits[]."_source".created_at, .events.total_fees.value, .events.latest.value] | @csv' input.json
```

You'll get something like this:

```
"056c65ec-22f6-4da1-9bce-82c12ed845cd","5.90",1681211194150,0.3499999940395355,1681289446844
```